# Swift code to query AWS dynamoDB data base

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I am building an app in Swift 2.3 and Xcode 8 and I need my app to query user information from a database (answers to questions they have answered earlier and saved in the database).
I have found some code (see it below) but I only get errors. I think that the problem is that code is looking for a specific item and I need to search the hash key for the unique id of the user so that every user who query's for their answers will get their specific information... any suggestions??

```
func updateAnswer() {  
    //first create expression
    let queryExpression = AWSDynamoDBQueryExpression()

    //second define the index name
    queryExpression.indexName = "userID-index"

    //3rd hashes
    queryExpression.hashKeyAttribute = "userID"
    queryExpression.hashKeyValues = ("us-east-1:97335bac-26d1-4b85-bc86-47091900df44")

    let dynamoDBObjectMapper = AWSDynamoDBObjectMapper.defaultDynamoDBObjectMapper()

    //tableRow?.UserId --> (tableRow?.UserId)!
    dynamoDBObjectMapper .query(Notes.self, expression: queryExpression) .continueWithExecutor(AWSExecutor.mainThreadExecutor(), withBlock: { (task:AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
        if (task.error == nil) {
            if (task.result != nil) {
                let note = task.result as! Notes
                self.driverAccomplishment1.text = note._content
            }
        } else {
            print("Error: \(task.error)")
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Failed to get item from table.", message: task.error!.description, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: { (action:UIAlertAction) -> Void in
            })
            alertController.addAction(okAction)
            self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)

        }
        return nil
    })
}
```

Comment: What is the error your are getting?

Comment: Depending on what I put in the index name and the hashkey attribute or value I get an access error from AWS ("Code 6 - access denied) or I get my error message. So I presume that seeing as I get the second message that I am getting through to the database. Thoughts???

Comment: Have you set your IAM policy correctly? You need to allow the "dynamodb:Query" Action for your table

Comment: Peter - thank you for the response and for your great tutorial on AWS! I do have the policies set correctly (I believe) because when I change the hash keys i get my error message (not the Code 6 referenced above). I believe that the code above is incorrect as it is currently trying to pull one specific user and I need the code to select the actual user and then pull the answer to a question they answered in a different part of the app.... does that help anyone think of a suggestion???